# Connect to Oracle database from asp.net core

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2017, database-connection, asp.net-core-2.0

First off I have read other posts about connecting to an Oracle database, unfortunately they could not help me. I'll describe what I have tried and hopefully someone can point me in the correct direction.

First off I tried to install ODTwithODAC122010 as many sources are saying,but this one gives me a few  process exited with non zero exit code. It says it's successful but nothing seems to be changed.

Next to that I tried installing ODTforVS2017_122010.exe I have an updated Visual Studio professional. It says the installation is a success. This however does not seems to add any option like tutorials describe. With this I mean that there should be something visible in;

visual studio tools -> connect to database -> Oracle database, data provider menu should have something like Oracle for.. This doesn't show up unfortunately..

So I tried connecting to the database in my visual studio project selecting the .net framework data provider for oracle. Here three fields are asked: Server name username and password. I tried filling them in but it couldn't connect.
For server name I used: IPADDRESS:PORT/SERVICENAME

After that I gave up hope for connecting to the database through visual studio (I can connect to the database using oracle SQL developer).

Then I installing the following nuget packages: 
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
- System.Security.Permissions
- System.Security.Principal

And wrote a piece of code to connect to the database like:

```
using(OracleConnection connect = new OracleConnection(ConnectionDetails.returnConnectionString()))
{
    connect.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("did it work?" + connect.ServerVersion);
}
```

Where returnConnectionString returns:

```
"User Id=MYID;Password=MYPASSWORD;Data Source=IPADDRESS:PORT/SERVICENAME"
```

Unfortunately when I try to run this I'm facing a ExecutionContext.cs not found. This is happening at connect.open();

I'm launching this code at:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new DatabaseConnector();
        a.test();
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
```

As I final word I want to make it clear that I'm using ASP.NET Core and that your suggestions and help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be precise,

1. Right click on your project
2. Go to Manage NuGet packages
3. Search for Oracle.manageddataaccess.core . You will get Nuget package 2.12.0-beta2 version. Add it.
4. In the page, import as below to access oracle classes

   using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

This is a beta version of Oracle data access provider and PROD version is supposed to be available at the end of 3rd quarter of 2018.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no ODP.NET support for .NET Core, it was suppose to be released last year, but there's been no news more than and [it's coming tweet](https://twitter.com/OracleDOTNET/status/955487498922164224) from the ODP twitter account a couple of weeks ago.

You can make the current version work by moving your project from .netcoreapp2 to a net461 or higher target framework, but it would remove the cross platform support from your project.

In order to move your project to .net461 or any other follow this steps:

1. Edit your csproj file and replace the `TargetFramework` with net461
2. If you have a web project then remove the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package and install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` (which should download the others dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

At the time of asking this question there was no driver Roy Sanchez answered that. A few weeks the driver got released on the oracle site and a as a nuget package.